# How to flush a ChiselUtil Queue?

Tags: scala, chisel

There is a Queue in ChiselUtil class that is described in manual as :

```
// Generic hardware queue. Required
// parameter entries controls the
// depth of the queues. The width of
// the queue is determined from the
// inputs.
// Example usage:
//    val q = new Queue(UInt(), 16)
//    q.io.enq <> producer.io.out
//    consumer.io.in <> q.io.deq
class Queue[T <: Data]
    (type: T, entries: Int,
     pipe: Boolean = false,
     flow: Boolean = false
     flushable: Boolean = false)
    extends Module
```

But in the scala code, interface parameters are different :
https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel/blob/master/src/main/scala/ChiselUtil.scala#L426

There is no "flushable" boolean input in code. I can't find the meaning of "pipe" and "flow" parameter.

Is somebody know how to use a Queue to be able to flush it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `flushable` parameter does not exist. Not sure what they meant by that. However, there is a way to clear a Queue by tapping into the `_reset' parameter, as shown below:

```
val my_queue = Module(new Queue(gen = new MyBundle,
                            entries = queue_sz,
                               pipe = false,
                               flow = true,
                             _reset = (kill_queue || reset.toBool)))
```

The `flow` parameter specifies whether inputs can be consumed on the same cycle (the inputs "flow" through the queue immediately). The "valid" signals are coupled.

The `pipe` parameter specifies whether the "ready" signals are combinationally coupled. This allows a one entry queue to run at full throughput (like a pipeline).

Comment: Thanks @Chris. You think that is a good way to use the _reset signal for flushing ?